# JQuery Toggle Help

Tags: jquery, html, height, toggle

this code here opens a div and animates it.. right? Yes, this works for me fine...

```
jQuery("a.trigger").click(function(){
    $("#main").animate({
      height: "+=300px"
    }, 1500 );
    return false;
});
```

My questions is, how can i toggle it? I can open it but how i close it...means... slideup 200px in height. Do you know what I mean?
I click on "read more" (a.trigger) and it animtes the height +200px.. but I also want to animte it back to -200px.

And I'm stuck because I'm not an jquery expert. I tried to use SlideToggle or toggle but it hasn't worked for me....

thanks for you help!

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem but the `return false` is redundant because JavaScript implicitly returns `undefined` if you don't return a value from a function, and both `false` and `undefined` are falsy values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am reading this correctly, then this is what you want to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/JqN4p/

Comment: no I meant the inital state... the div has already 470px and I want to extend it with approx. 300px more (slidedown)

Comment: well, you could do like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JqN4p/2/ however its not very polished. if you click multiple times very fast on read more then you will see bugs in the animation.

Answer (score 2):

mabey by setting a class which holds the state

```
jQuery("a.trigger").click(function(){
    if (!$("#main").is(".open")) {
        $("#main").animate({
            height: "+=300px"
        }, 1500 ).addClass('open');
    } else {
        $("#main").animate({
            height: "-=300px"
        }, 1500 ).removeClass('open');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the toggle function.

```
jQuery("a.trigger").toggle(function(){
  $("#main").animate({
    height: "+=300px"
    }, 1500 );
    return false;
  }, function(){
  $("#main").animate({
    height: "-=300px"
  }, 1500 );
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("a.trigger").toggle(function()
{
    $("#main").animate (... height+=300));
}, function()
{
    $("#main").animate (... height-=300));
});
```

alternatively you can use slideToggle:

```
jQuery("a.trigger").click(function(){ $("#main").slideToggle(); });
```

Comment: also with a fixed height for the div? my #main div has a start height of 472px in the css?

Comment: If you want your div to partially slide down, then you should go for the first code, if you want it to fully slide down and up second one can work.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("a.trigger").click(function(){
   if( $("#main").hasClass('active') )
        value  = -300;
   else
      value = 300; 
    $("#main").addClass('active').animate({
      height: "+=" + value + 'px'
    }, 1500 );
    return false;
});
```

Here's a working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/QVJPZ/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery slideToggle will do this for you nicely:

```
$('a.trigger').click(function() {
  $('#main').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/